# Equivalent for Javascript's Math.sign but for Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

> The Math.sign() function returns either a positive or negative  +/- 1, indicating the sign of a number passed into the argument..  If the number passed into Math.sign() is 0, it will return a +/- 0.  Note that if the number is positive, an explicit (+) will not be returned.

Can this be done in dart - perhaps with the Maths library? I searched but couldn't find much about it.

Comment: see `num.sign` property

Comment: @pskink `num` seems to only contain the functions `parse` and `tryParse`. Is there something I need to import? I have imported the maths library but that doesn't seem to affect it.

Comment: [num.sign](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.1/dart-core/num/sign.html)

Comment: @pskink Ok I was using it wrongly. Thanks it works great.

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure what to do with this question, either delete it or answer it. The solution as provided by `pskink` is to use `num.sign` which does not require the Dart Maths library.

It's usage is as follows:

```
var a = 5;
var b = -32;
var c = a.sign; //without ()
var d = b.sign;
print(c); // 1;
print(d); // -1;
```

and not `sign(b)` as I was using it.

Comment: Glad you didn't delete the question, it's still useful to Googlers years later!